# Retriving data row that matches all conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image]

"Great Indian Sale Discount" would be applied if all the conditions are satisfied.
context can have multiple context_subCategory values.
Negative grouping means mandatory conditions.
Positive grouping number means optional conditions but one of the optional conditions must be true.

"Great Indian Sale Discount" would be applied if

- context Party and subCategry partyLocation is not equal to (NOT=) Australia
- context Order and order Type = cash
  and one of the below is true (positive grouping Number)
- Customer context and subcategroy customer Name = Shubh
- Customer context and customer Id = 12
- Customer context and customer Location = Canberra

I am looking for clean approach for solving the problem. I need to select from multiple Discount Names that matches the conditions.
subcategory and its values are incoming parameters i.e. party Location, Australia are coming as parameters.

my approach uses a lot of case statements.
context are always same Party, Order or Customer, but sub category can be different for different discount Name.

below is code for optional case. similarly, I am having one mandatoryCount for mandatory options.
if both optionalCount and mandatoryCount are > 0, I'll select that discount Name.

```
SET @sql  = 'SET @optionalCount = (select count(*) from #discountData where ' + (            
 SELECT CASE WHEN @context = 'PARTY'            
      THEN 'CONTEXT = ''' + @context + ''' and context_value= ' + (case statment for selecting subcategory )          
      WHEN @context = 'CUSTOMER'            
      THEN 'CONTEXT = ''' + @context + ''' and context_value= ' + (case statment for selecting subcategory)          
      WHEN @context = 'ORDER'            
      THEN 'CONTEXT = ''' + @context + ''' and context_value= ' + (case statment for selecting subcategory)             
      END            
) + ')'
```

Is there any other better way of achieving the same?

Comment: Are you really using *both* SQL Server 2005 and 2012? They are both **completely** unsupported, and have been for around 9 and 2 years respectively. You really need to migrate to a recent, supported version, especially that 2005 instance; you should have finalised that upgrade plan about a decade ago.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: As for your question, define "better". The SQL you've given us is incomplete, so better than *what*?

Comment: removed tags for sql server 2005 and 2012. They were added accidentally.

Comment: Do what version are you *really* using..?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Sql server 2014

Comment: It's not clear where these contexts, subcategories, and values come from? If from a table, can we see it's table definition?

Comment: for the sake of the exercise of getting the query straight you should post the clean SQL without any parameterization. When your SQL works, then you parameterize

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit ugly but perhaps you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT  [Discount Name], STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN asign = -1 THEN 'WHERE 1 = 1 ' ELSE ' AND(1 = 0 ' END + aggvalue + CASE WHEN asign = 1 THEN ')' ELSE '' END, '') within GROUP(ORDER BY asign)
FROM    (
    SELECT  [Discount Name]
    ,   SIGN([grouping number]) AS asign
    ,   STRING_AGG(CONCAT(CASE sign([grouping number]) WHEN 1 THEN ' OR ' ELSE 'AND ' END,'(context = ', quotename(context, ''''), ' AND ', quotename(context_subcategory), replace(operator, 'NOT=', '<>'), quotename(context_value, ''''), ')'), '') AS aggValue
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (N'Great Indian Sale Discount', -1, N'Party', N'partyLocation', N'Australia', N'NOT=')
        ,   (N'Great Indian Sale Discount', -1, N'Order', N'ordertype', N'cash', N'=')
        ,   (N'Great Indian Sale Discount', 1, N'Customer', N'customerName', N'shubh', N'=')
        ,   (N'Great Indian Sale Discount', 2, N'Customer', N'customerid', N'12', N'=')
        ,   (N'Great Indian Sale Discount', 3, N'Customer', N'customer Location', N'Canberra', N'=')
    ) t ([Discount Name],[grouping number],context,context_subCategory,context_value,operator)
    
    GROUP BY sign([grouping number]), [Discount Name]
    ) x
GROUP BY [Discount Name]
```

You group per discount and sign of the grouping number, one for mandatory and one for optional parameters. Then you aggregate the conditions into a string and handle the ANDs and ORs.

Then in the outer aggregation you put them together and create the final WHERE condition.

The above outputs:

`WHERE 1 = 1 AND (context = 'Order' AND [ordertype]='cash')AND (context = 'Party' AND [partyLocation]<>'Australia') AND(1 = 0  OR (context = 'Customer' AND [customerid]='12') OR (context = 'Customer' AND [customer Location]='Canberra') OR (context = 'Customer' AND [customerName]='shubh'))`

It shouldn't be too hard to customize the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The values Australia as 'country', cash as 'orderType' and so on for  shubh, 12 would be coming from the outside as parameters. i have to use case expressions for that like CASE WHEN context = 'Order' and contextsubCategory = 'orderType' THEN 'orderType' variable value WHEN context = 'Party' and contextsubCategory='party Location' then 'country' variable value and so on. Is there any approach where we don't need to use the case expressions.

Comment: I don't see any problems, just change [customer Location] etc. to the incoming parameters